# Perform aggregation and transformation in pandas dataframe based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe `df1`.

```
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.DataFrame([[1,11,'mx212', 1000], [1,11,'rx321', 600], 
                 [1,11,'/bc1', 5],[1,11,'/bc2', 11], [1,12,'sx234', 800],
                 [1,12,'mx456', 1232], [3,13,'mx322', 1000], [3,13,'/bc3', 34]], 
                 columns=["sale","order","code","amt"])

   sale  order  code   amt
0   1    11     mx212  1000
1   1    11     rx321  600
2   1    11     /bc1    5
3   1    11     /bc2    11
4   1    12     sx234   800
5   1    12     mx456   1232
6   3    13     mx322   1000
7   3    13     /bc3    34
```

Here, a saleperson can have multiple orders and each order can have multiple codes. I want to aggregate and transform `amt` based on specific combinations of `sale`, `order` and `code`. A `code` starting with *"/bc"* needs to be aggregated with main `code` value("starting with values like 'mx','rx' etc). **Note that any `code` value not staring with `/bc` is considered type "main"**.  If there are multiple combinations of `code` values of type *"/bc"* and *"main"* type, the aggregation for `amt` should be done on each combination(for eq rows 1, 2, 3 and 4 has two combinations of type *"main"* and *"/bc"*. Note that, a specific `order` would have equal values of `code` types *"/bc"* and *"main"*. Once, the aggregation for an `order` is done, i want the `code` type *"/bc"* to be dropped.

If a particular `sale` and `order` has no `code` type *"bc"*, the values of "amt" should be same. For eq, rows 5 and 6 should be unchanged and `code`, `amt` values should remain same.

The resulting dataframe `df2` should ideally be this:

```
    sale  order  code   amt
 0   1    11     mx212  1005
 1   1    11     rx321   611
 2   1    12     sx234   800
 3   1    12     mx456   1232
 4   3    13     mx322   1034
```

`amt` value in row 1 is "1000+5" and in row 2 is "600+11"{`code` type *"main"* is added to respective *"/bc"*. `amt` values in row 3 and 4 remains same and in row 5, it is "1000+34".

I know this is a lot of information, but i tried to be as coherent as possible. I would request if there are any questions, please comment. I will appreciate it. Any kind of help is always welcomed :)

Comment: I still don't understand how you decide to add the `amt` corresponding to `bc/1` to `mx212`, for example

Comment: The thing is that they are in the same order, for eq a set of  {mx,rx etc} would be followed by set of "/bc". So, 1st "mx" would be added with first "/bc" etc. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I break down the steps...key is building a column help to determine the inner group

```
df1.code=df1.code.replace({'bc':np.nan},regex=True)
df1['New']=df1.code.isnull()
d1=df1.groupby([df1.sale,df1.order,df1.groupby(['sale','order','New']).cumcount()],as_index=False).amt.sum()
pd.concat([d1,df1.dropna().code.reset_index(drop=True)],1)

Out[344]: 
   sale  order   amt   code
0     1     11  1005  mx212
1     1     11   611  rx321
2     1     12   800  sx234
3     1     12  1232  mx456
4     3     13  1034  mx322
```

Comment: Nice @wen.  +1  Good answer.

Comment: Your reasoning amazes me. Thanks again.

Comment: @VenkateshMalhotra Yw~ Man :-)

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like this:

```
g=df1.groupby(['sale','order',df1.code.str.startswith('/bc')]).cumcount()

df1.groupby(['sale','order',g],as_index=False)['amt','code']\
   .agg({'code':'first','amt':'sum'})
```

Output:

```
   sale  order   code   amt
0     1     11  mx212  1005
1     1     11  rx321   611
2     1     12  sx234   800
3     1     12  mx456  1232
4     3     13  mx322  1034
```

Comment: Nice one haha :-)